# Socket.io: First Client disconnecting on Second connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am creating a socket.io app. When I create a connection to the socket on firefox, it established just fine. When I am using chrome to init another connection to the socket, the first client gets disconnected and then the two clients reconnect again (with the same socket.id)

This is the code I have been working with:

```
app.post('/auth', function(req, res){   // routes.auth(hash, db, io, pseudoArray, connections, Session));
    var username = req.body.username,
        password = req.body.password;
    if (username != "" && password != ""){
        authenticate(username, password, db, hash, function(err, user){
            if (user) {
                // Regenerate session when signing in
                // to prevent fixation 
                console.log('user authenticated');
                req.session.regenerate(function(){
                    req.session.user = user.name;
                    req.session.success = 'Authenticated as ' + user.name
                    + ' click to <a href="/logout">logout</a>. '
                    + ' You may now access <a href="/restricted">/restricted</a>.'; 

                    var Session = connect.middleware.session.Session;
                    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
                        var hs = socket.handshake;
                        console.log('A socket with sessionID ' + hs.sessionID + ' connected!');

                        socket.set('pseudo', req.session.user, function(){
                            pseudoArray.push(req.session.user);
                            socket.emit('pseudoStatus', req.session.user);
                            console.log("user " + req.session.user + " connected");
                        });

                        socket.on('pseudoOk', function(data){
                        //  connections[data] = socket; 
                            connections[data] = socket.id; // connected user with its socket.id
                            connectedUsers[socket.id] = socket;

                            console.log('----CONNECTIONS----');
                            console.log(connections);
                            console.log('++ USERS ++ ');
                            console.log(connectedUsers);
                            console.log('----END CONNECTIONS----');
                        });

                        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                            console.log('A socket with sessionID ' + hs.sessionID + ' disconnected!');

                            // clear the socket interval to stop refreshing the session
                            // clearInterval(intervalID);
                        });
                    });

                    res.cookie('rememberme', '1', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
                    res.redirect('home');
                });
            } else {
                console.log('auth failed');
                req.session.error = 'Authentication failed, please check your '
                    + ' username and password.'
                    + ' (use "tj" and "foobar")';
                res.redirect('login');
            }
        }); 
    } else {
        res.redirect('connect');
    }
});
```

Any clues?

**The main question is:** Will a socket connection on a single computer (localhost) work within two different browsers on the same machine? What I am thinking is that since I am using two browsers on a single machine, I am getting the same socket id for both the browsers. Is that the case?

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: i have added the code to the post.

Comment: @amit you're setting up `socket.io` connection handlers from within HTTP request handlers, which is not how things are supposed to be done and will most likely result it all sorts of undefined behaviour (and memory leaks probably).

Comment: @robertklep i am a n00b. can you please explain it a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an event listener on the socket.io `connection` event for every POST request to `/auth`. That's going to result in undefined behaviour and possibly memory leaks. Express and socket.io are two separate subsystems running within the same server application. As such, they shouldn't be mixed like that.

A 'normal' Express/socket.io setup looks like this:

```
// your Express routes
app.post('/auth', function(req, res) { ... });
...

// socket.io setup (completely separate)
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  ...
});
```

If you want to share session objects between Express and socket.io: that isn't trivial. Like I said before, both systems should be considered separate from each other. However, there have been some clever people [that got it to work](http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth). I don't know how up-to-date that blogpost is, though, and it requires quite in-depth knowledge of both Express and socket.io.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will go separate the two and report back. just one thing, will 2 different browsers on the same machine be able to create a socket connection between them with separate id's ?

Comment: @amit browsers cannot set up a connection directly to each other, if that's what you mean; but if you mean if two different browsers on the same machine can connect to your server and get a separate id, then yes (in fact, every new connection will get a new id, even if those connections are built up by the same browser, but perhaps in different tabs/windows)